# remove everything within [] /\[[^][]*]/g

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to remove everything that is inside this: []
To example [abcd]word[efg] should be word. I tried to replace it like this but its not working for some reason. Does anyone know how to fix that?

```js
string = '[abcd]word[efg]';
string = string.replace(/\[[^][]*]/g,"");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: you'll have to escape the `[` and `]` due to it having a special meaning in regex

Comment: To remove "everything *within* []" from `"[abcd]word[efg]"` you should get `"[]word[]"`, but that's evidently not what you want. Please be precise in your wording.

Comment: @Daniel, not quite. See me comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: `\[[^\]\[]*\]` (you forgot some escaping)

```js
    string = '[abcd]word[efg]';
    string = string.replace(/\[[^\]\[]*\]/g,"");
    console.log(string);
```

Comment: It's not necessary to escape `'['` within the character class or the terminating `']'`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSxWrU/1)

Comment: If you mean it should only be `/\[[^][]*\]/g` then I just tried and it doesn't work, you have to escape those

Comment: Raz, the simplification I suggested is shown in the link in my comment: `\[[^\][]*]`. `']'` in a character class must be escaped, for if it were not the regex engine would view it as ending the character class. It's not necessary, however, to escape `'['` within a character class, as it causes no confusion to Javascript's regex engine.